# Mi función JavaScript me borra en titulo de un Combobox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Lo que pasa es que se me presento un pequeño problema en un `script` que lo que hace es que carga items en un `ComboBox` mediante un id dependiendo que id cargue, aquí esta el código Javascript:

```
function Opciones() {
    var opc = $('#seguro option:selected').val();
//  $("#DivPension").load("/aplicativos/simulador-pensiones/opciones.jsp", {
    $("#DivPension").load("views/opciones.jsp", {
        opcion: opc
    });
    setTimeout(enlasaEvento, 250);
    enlasaEvento();
}
```

Lo que hace esta función es invocar un `jsp` que es el encarga de lanzar los `items`, que el jsp seria:

```
<%
    int valor = Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("opcion")==""?"0":request.getParameter("opcion")));
    if(valor==1){
%>
<select name="pension"  id="pension">
  <option selected="selected" value="">--Seleccione--</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="1" id="TdPInvalidez">Invalidez</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="3" id="TdPVO">Viudez y Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="4" id="TdPVI">Viudez</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="5" id="TdPOR">Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="6" id="TdPASC">Ascendencia</option>
</select>
<%
    }else if(valor==2){
%>
<select name="pension"  id="pension">
    <option selected="selected" value="">--Seleccione--</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="2" id="TdPIncapacidad">Incapacidad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="3" id="TdPVO">Viudez y Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="4" id="TdPVI">Viudez</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="5" id="TdPOR">Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="6" id="TdPASC">Ascendencia</option>
</select>
<%
    }else if(valor==3){
%>
<select name="pension"  id="pension">
    <option selected="selected" value="">--Seleccione--</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="3" id="TdPVO">Viudez y Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="4" id="TdPVI">Viudez</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="5" id="TdPOR">Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="6" id="TdPASC">Ascendencia</option>
</select>
<%
    }else if(valor==0){
%>

<select name="pension"  id="pension">
    <option selected="selected">--Seleccione--</option>
</select>
<%
    }
%>
```

Y la pantalla (vista) asi seria al cargar por primera vez:

[image: Asi se presenta la imagen]

Y el problema esta aqui:

[image: Aqui desaparece el titulo del segundo comboBox]

Por ultimo el HTML seria:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
        <script src="../comun/js/jquery_v1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/EnmascaraV2-AEM.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_MD.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataLayer/dataLayer.js"></script><!--listo-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataLayer/dataLayer_.js"></script><!--listo-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataLayer/funciones_dataLayer.js"></script><!--listo-->

        <script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/95bb966a4c61b200a089c37679aaf96e22114787/satelliteLib-fbdb84ebd99368b1f7fb97b75596c095b9f7ee40-staging.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!--listo-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/seleccion.js"></script><!--listo-->

        <script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/95bb966a4c61b200a089c37679aaf96e22114787/mbox-contents-a552a4edacd46d5f42cf557b1157973f26c55845.js"></script>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#seguro').val('');
                $('#pension').val('');
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Simulador Pensión</h1>
            <h2>Descubre a través de este simulador, cual podría ser un aproximado del monto de Pensión que
                recibirás de acuerdo a los datos que nos proporciones.</h2>
            <form>

                <div class="botonera">      
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                        <div class="group">
                            <select class="select" name="seguro" class="Caja_txt_246" tabindex="9" id="seguro" onchange="Opciones()" >
                                <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>
                                <option value="1" id="TDSIV">Invalidez y Vida</option>
                                <option value="2" id="TDSRT">Riesgo de trabajo</option>
                                <option value="3" id="TDSRCV">Retiro y Cesantía</option>
                            </select>
                             <label class="combo">Tipo de Seguro</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                        <div class="group" id="DivPension">
                            <select name="pension" class="Caja_txt_246" id="pension" tabindex="9">
                                <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>
                            </select>


                            <label class="combo">Tipo de Pensión</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="botonera">      
                    <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                        <button type="submit" id="loginButton"  onclick="validar(event);" >Siguiente</button>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

La verdad no sé que hacer con este problema, ya que había solucionado un problema en validar los campos si están vacíos mediante el evento `"event.preventDefault();"` y ya quedo, espero y me puedan ayudar, de antemano les mando un cordial saludo.

Como un detalle mas, el .load es el que carga el contenido del jsp y al igual me borra el label del input.

Answer (score 1):

La función `.load` de jQuery cargará el contenido HTML de la URL y lo pondrá en el elmento que se indica en el selector. Por ejemplo:

```
$("#DivPension").load("views/opciones.jsp", {
    opcion: opc
});
```

Cargará el contenido de `views/opciones.jsp` en el div `#DivPension`. Eso significa que **se sustituirá el contenido completo de `#DivPension` por el del código cargado via AJAX**. Y ahí es donde está el problema, porque ese div se ve así:

```
<div class="group" id="DivPension">
    <select name="pension" class="Caja_txt_246" id="pension" tabindex="9">
        <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>
    </select>


    <label class="combo">Tipo de Pensión</label>
</div>
```

Con lo cual cuando se carguen los valores por AJAX, no sólo se borrará el `select` sino también el `label` que quieres que se mantenga. Una opción para solucionar esto sería devolver el `label` también a través del JSP. Por ejemplo:

```
<%
    int valor = Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("opcion")==""?"0":request.getParameter("opcion")));
    if(valor==1){
%>
<select name="pension"  id="pension">
  <option selected="selected" value="">--Seleccione--</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="1" id="TdPInvalidez">Invalidez</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="3" id="TdPVO">Viudez y Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="4" id="TdPVI">Viudez</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="5" id="TdPOR">Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="6" id="TdPASC">Ascendencia</option>
</select>
<label class="combo">Tipo de Pensión</label>
<%
    }else if(valor==2){
%>
<select name="pension"  id="pension">
    <option selected="selected" value="">--Seleccione--</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="2" id="TdPIncapacidad">Incapacidad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="3" id="TdPVO">Viudez y Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="4" id="TdPVI">Viudez</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="5" id="TdPOR">Orfandad</option>
    <option name="TdP" value="6" id="TdPASC">Ascendencia</option>
</select>
<label class="combo">Tipo de Pensión</label>
<%
    ....
```

---

Otra opción, que no sé si es posible porque no sé cómo está estructurado tu código HTML/CSS/JS completo, sería mover `#DivPension` un nivel más abajo. Algo como esto:

```
<div class="group">
    <div id="DivPension">
        <select name="pension" class="Caja_txt_246" id="pension" tabindex="9">
            <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <label class="combo">Tipo de Pensión</label>
</div>
```

De este modo sólo se sustituirá el `select`, manteniendo el `label`.

Comment: Hola @Alvaro Montaro De echo si funciona las dos opciones que me das, pero la que opté mas fue la segunda opción, muchas gracias por la gran ayuda que me diste, te lo agradezco, saludos donde quieras que estes, amigo! :)

Comment: Me alegro que te hayan servido las dos respuestas. Si esto solucionó tu problema, deberías marcar la respuesta como aceptada en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.